# How can I print or display first 20 characters of the dataitem.message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help.. how can I print or display first 20 characters of the dataitem.message. For two days now I have been battling with this.

Please, see attached image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82J40.jpg)

I have used dataItem.message.substring(0, 20) but it is still not working

Comment: Please do not give [code by image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the `substrings` as an argument to `dataItem.message`. I will suggest you use `slice` method. so instead of using `dataItem.message.substring(0, 20)` use `dataItem.message.slice(0,20)`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If dataItem.message's type is anything but a string. The substring won't help.
Try to
`console.log(dataItem.message)`
And see what type it is.
Otherwise it'll be tough to help much more without also seeing where dataItem is created and updated in your code.

Comment: I also use other javascript splitting, but it did not work. its a sttring